# Jupyter command 'jupyter-notebook' not found, despite jupyter and notebook being installed

Tags: python, windows, intellij-idea, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

When I try to run a .ipynb file in Intellij, or when i input 'python -m jupyter notebook' into the terminal, I always receive the error "Jupyter command 'jupyter-notebook' not found".

I use Windows 10, Intellij-Ultimate 2023.1, python 3.10.11, jupyter 1.0.0, jupyter-notebook 6.5.4, jupyter core 5.3.0.

When I initially installed jupyter, it warned that the installed .exe files were installed in a directory not located in the PATH variable. I added that directory to PATH, but that didn't change anything.

I have used pip and IntelliJ to install Jupyter separately on different occasions, this doesn't fix the issue. If I use 'pip show jupyter' or 'pip show notebook' it shows them as installed, jupyter version 1.0.0, notebook version 6.5.4. It shows them as located in "user\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python310\site-packages" and indeed they are.

Under the View > Tool Windows > Python Packages tab in Intellij, it displays jupyter, but not notebook, although notebook is a requirement for jupyter. Another installed package "jupyter-core" says in its description that it contains jupyter-notebook.

I've already tried uninstalling and installing, or updating all of the jupyter/notebook packages.

jupyter itself seems to work, and opens a browser when called.

I have not found another questions which contains these circumstances, does anybody have any other idea how else I could try to solve this error?

Edit: This is still not resolved. I don't know if the bot is actually saying something useful, but here: I would like for Jupyter-notebook to work when called upon with `python -m jupyter notebook` or IntelliJ's run function.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please check if you have `jupyter-notebook.exe` in `<python_installation/Scripts>` directory. If you do, you probably need to add this directory to your PATH env variable
---
How to configure environment variables in Windows: https://www.architectryan.com/2018/08/31/how-to-change-environment-variables-on-windows-10/

Comment: I indeed have ´´jupyter-notebook.exe´´ in user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\Scripts, and that path is in my PATH variable already. That was the path i was warned about by the system. However, my python.exe is in my WindowsApps folder, might that cause problems?